# Why does my iOS app produce a dyld error on launch?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, linker-errors, dyld

I have a project running on Xcode 12.3; it's in Objective-C and uses CocoaPods. The 3rd party libraries are built only for devices, not for simulators, so when I run my app on iPhone with iOS 13, the project builds successfully but I get the following error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _$s9SwiftGRPC17ServerSessionBaseC15initialMetadataAA0G0CvM
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE50CA2F-F5D6-4DF3-B76F-2E580D604C4B/####.app/Frameworks/Core.framework/Core
  Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE50CA2F-F5D6-4DF3-B76F-2E580D604C4B/####.app/Frameworks/SwiftGRPC.framework/SwiftGRPC
 in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EE50CA2F-F5D6-4DF3-B76F-2E580D604C4B/####.app/Frameworks/Core.framework/Core
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUTools.framework/libglInterpose.dylib:/usr/lib/libMTLCapture.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
(lldb)
```

The pod file is as below:

```
pod 'SwiftGRPC', '~> 0.9.0'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'CleverTap-iOS-SDK', '~> 3.7.1'
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION` to `true` for all your frameworks to ensure module stability?

You'll need to set the flag to true in your app (under project settings) as well as in your dependencies by adding a post install script at the end of your Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```

Original solution [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9775#issuecomment-722298424)